# Lua garbage collector stops collecting automatically

Tags: c++, c, lua, garbage-collection

I noticed that after running my game for a while, the memory consumption starts increasing. I managed to narrow down the problem - executing this once per frame causes the memory issue:

```
    lua_newtable(L);
    lua_pop(L, 1);
```

I added a debug log to check how much memory Lua is using:

```
    printf("Memory used: %d\n", lua_gc(L, LUA_GCCOUNT, 0));
```

This revealed that the memory usage stays fine for about 30 seconds, going up and down as the garbage collector does its job. Then the memory stops coming down. Obviously the garbage collector stops working.

I tested resetting the garbage collector on every frame (less would probably be enough) and it fixes the issue.

```
    lua_gc(L, LUA_GCRESTART, 0);
```

Why is Lua doing this to me? I can't find anyone else having the same problem.

I am using Lua 5.1.5 on Windows.

Comment: How long have you left things sit and grow? Could this just be the way the step and pause behavior works out with the current memory usage?

Comment: Long enough for the application to crash.

Comment: How long was that? Was the memory increasing the entire time? Crash why? (Out of memory?) Make sure you don't have multiple lua runtimes linked in to your app by accident. Also make sure you aren't corrupting the stack? (Turn on lua api assertions.)

Comment: Not sure exactly, but at least more than an hour. The memory kept increasing and finally crashed because out of memory. Could stack corruption cause the memory to behave this weird without any other symptoms? I'll try the assertions.

Comment: Try lua_pop(L, -1);